# Create new array based on element position

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like so

```
$dataArray = array(
    array( 20800, 21679, 0 ),
    array( 15254, 0, 3726 ),
    array( 17426, 2973, 0 ),
    array( 4391, 37, 0 ),
    array( 39194, 435, 0 )
);
```

I am creating a sub array from this.  Any value greater than 2000 becomes a 1, otherwise it becomes a 0.

```
foreach ($dataArray as $row => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if($value > 1999) {
            $dataArray[$row][$key] = 1;
        } else {
            $dataArray[$row][$key] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following

```
$dataArray = array(
    array( 1, 1, 0 ),
    array( 1, 0, 1 ),
    array( 1, 1, 0 ),
    array( 1, 0, 0 ),
    array( 1, 0, 0 )
);
```

Now what I am trying to do is produce another array that shows the positions of the 1's within the above array.  Each row should be represented by a new array.  The output I am looking for is this

```
$dataArray = array(
    array( 1, 2 ),
    array( 1, 3 ),
    array( 1, 2 ),
    array( 1 ),
    array( 1 )
);
```

So I can see that row 1 has a 1 in position 1 and 2, row 2 has a 1 in positions 1 and 3 etc.

I wanted to make use of my current loop, so I am trying something like this

```
$position = array();

foreach ($dataArray as $row => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if($value > 1999) {
            $position[$row] = $key + 1;
            $dataArray[$row][$key] = 1;
        } else {
            $dataArray[$row][$key] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

But this seems way off according to my output.  How can I achieve what I am after?

Thanks

Comment: `$position[$row][]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$dataArray = array(
    array( 20800, 21679, 0 ),
    array( 15254, 0, 3726 ),
    array( 17426, 2973, 0 ),
    array( 4391, 37, 0 ),
    array( 39194, 435, 0 )
);
$endResult = [];

foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
   foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
    if ($subvalue >= 2000) {
       $endResult[$key][] = $subkey +1;
    }
   }
}

print_r($endResult);

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )
)
```

Comment: I like this solution the most as it skips creating the initial array with 1s and 0s, thanks

Comment: don't forget to use short array syntax as of PHP5.6 ;) `[ ]`

Comment: You could use `$key` instead of `$i`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/array_map) along with [`array_keys`](http://www.php.net/array_keys):

```
$dataArray = [
  [1, 1, 0],
  [1, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 0],
  [1, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 0]
];

$onePositions = array_map(function($row) {
  return array_map(function($position) { return $position + 1; }, array_keys($row, 1));
}, $dataArray);

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($onePositions); echo '</pre>';
```

[Demo here](https://3v4l.org/X7lNS)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the second parameter in the [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function to get the positions after you populate the ones and zeros:

```
$position = array();
$binary = array();

foreach ($dataArray as $row => $data) {

    // if you want to have the positions start at 1 instead of 0
    // add a dummy value to the final array
    $binary[$row][] = 0;

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if($value > 1999) {
            $binary[$row][] = 1;
        } else {
            $binary[$row][] = 0;
        }
    }
    $positions[] = array_keys($binary[$row], 1);
}
```

[Demo Here](https://3v4l.org/YrPR7)